# Ajax data parameter to controller is always null

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How can i send both serialize object and string array to asp.net controller? 
My sample ajax is here=>

```
var $this = $("#FormName");
var frmValues = $this.serialize();
var sortorder = [];
$(".StepOrder").each(function (index) {
   sortorder.splice(index, 0, ($(this).attr('id')));
});                           

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  traditional:true,
  url: '/MyController/MyAction',
  datatype:'html',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data:JSON.stringify( { frmValues: frmValues, sortorder: sortorder }),
  success: function (data) {

  },
});
```

My Controller=>

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel frmValues,List<string> sortorder)
{
 return View();
}
```

MyModel and sortorder in controller are always null.I also try like=>

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: '/MyController/MyAction',
 data: { frmValues: frmValues, sortorder: sortorder },
 success: function (data) {

 },
});
```

It also don't work.I don't known why it doesn't work.

Comment: try `JSON.stringify({ frmValues: frmValues, sortorder: sortorder })`

Comment: I already try like that.It also don't work.:(

Comment: can you add view and MyModel  in the question

Comment: and also check the network tab in browser to check the request parameters

Comment: change datatype to json

Answer (score 3):

Using this approach, create a DTO class which the controller action accepts as request:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: '/MyController/MyAction',
 data: { frmValues: frmValues, sortorder: sortorder },
 success: function (data) {

 },
});
```

Then DTO Class as below, make sure the keys from payload match the property name.

```
public class ExampleDTO 
{
   public MyModel frmValues {get; set;}
   public List<string> sortorder {get; set;}
}
```

Use it as:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(ExampleDTO req)
{
  //var frmValues = req.frmValues;
  //string sortOrder = req.sortorder;
  return View();
}
```

Comment: It makes no difference it the parameters are in the method or in a model. This does nothing to solve OP's problem